# Need help understanding this decimal code

Tags: binary, hex, decimal

I am trying to understand what this decimal code would be as a binary:

[image: decimal problem]

I understand how to normally get the answer, because I would take 425 and then figure out that 256 + 128 + 32 + 8 + 1 = 425, which would be 110101001 in binary.

[image: process]

However, I am completely thrown off by the d in the decimal. How can I understand what it is and how to solve this (if the answer is different than 110101001)?

Comment: The `d` probably just means decimal.

Comment: The *d* simply indicates that it's a decimal (base 10) number. Nothing more.

Comment: Oh!! Wow, now I feel silly!

Comment: Thank you, @WHACKAMADOODLE3000 !

Comment: And @KenWhite  !!

Comment: You're welcome. You should delete this question, as it was a simple misunderstanding of the problem description on your part and won't really benefit others here in the future.